# How to replace a bean with a testing mock in Spring Boot for integration testing

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring app and integration tests for this app. I would like to replace a bean with a mock bean.

My real bean looks like this

```
@Service
public class MyService {

}
```

and for testing I would like it to be replaced

```
@Service
public class TestMyService {

}
```

All I can think of is to use profiles for different services. For example:

```
@Service
@Profile("!test")
public class MyService implements IMyService {

}

@Service
@Profile("test")
public class TestMyService implements IMyService {

}
```

And then I autowire the bean like this

```
@Autowired
private IMyService myService;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory answer? I am migrating from Springockito which has a handle ReplaceWithMock annotation that does exactly what you describe.  I havent been able to find an analog.

Comment: Puzzled as well...

Answer (score 8):

Spring Boot has `@MockBean` and `@SpyBean` annotations exactly for this purpose:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Declaration is simple:

```
@MockBean
private MyService myService;
```

Spring Boot will inject Mockito mock there instead of the actual bean.

Comment: It will not replace bean, just create another mock bean of same type and inject mock. Well, in some configurations this will bring duplicate bean exception

Comment: This is a bad answer.

Comment: new link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.mocking-beans

Comment: @KitKarson if you're going to comment "This is a bad answer" without providing any further explanation you might as well not comment at all.

Answer (score 7):

My personal preference is to avoid loading the compete context for testing. Therefore I like my test to focus on a subset of beans. It usually means I outline beans which I use in tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {TestMyService.class, OtherClassNeededForTesting.class}
)
public class DelaysProviderTest {

}
```

If more configuration is needed I tend to prepare a separate configuration class for tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = MyTest.Cfg.class
)
public class MyTest {

    @Import({
        // .. some classes to import including TestMyService.class
    })
    @Configuration
    public static class Cfg {

    }

}
```

When even more configuration is needed (or mocking), I use the test configuration for providing appropriate mocks

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = MyTest.Cfg.class
)
public class MyTest {

    @Import({
        // .. some classes to import
    })
    @Configuration
    public static class Cfg {

        @Bean
        public IMyService service() {
            IMyService mock = Mockito.mock(IMyService.class);
            when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn("some data");

            return mock;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: cool. Do you end up with 10 or 20 or 30 beans in the `@Import` section then?

Comment: I have multiple configuration with an applications (kind of modules / packages) where I mostly configure external dependencies (adapters, following ports and adapters architecture). Which helps me with encapsulation. Looking through the code, I don't see more than 6-8 imports within a single test.

Comment: Nice! I was having some hard time while trying to use @Spybean, which didn't work, no matter how I used it... thank you!

Comment: Can also use `@Import(MyTest.Cfg.class)` in cases where the `@SpringBootTest` is defined in the parent test class.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your beans, in your case something like

```
@Service("testService")    
public class TestMyService implements IMyService {

}
```

and in your test class, you can explicitely ask for test service using `@Qualifier`, like

```
@Qualifier("testService")
@Autowired
private IMyService myService;
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work when `IMyService` is a downstream dependency (an adapter) in your business code. `@Qualifier` allows you to inject the bean in the test class, but it's very limiting.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot, `@MockBean` (and  `@SpyBean`) are likely your best bets as noted in Grzegorz Poznachowski's answer.

**For non Spring Boot Applications**, an alternative is to use `@Primary` to annotate the mock/stub `@Bean`/`@Service` definition. That annotation "indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency." As such, your mock will be used over the "real" one when wiring other Beans/Configurations.

```
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(MyAppConfig.class)
public class MyUintTest 
{
    @Autowired
    private ServiceInterface serviceMock;

    @Autowired
    private SomeClass someClassMock;

    @Test
    public void myTest() 
    {
        when(someClassMock.getProperty()).thenReturn(properties.get());
        // . . .
    }

    @Service
    @Primary
    static class TestService implements ServiceInterface 
    {
        // . . .
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config 
    {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public SomeClass someClassBean() 
        {
            return Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
        }
    }
}
```